# scroll trigger not working on next js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a gsap animation with scroll trigger , animation works but doesnot work on trigger . AnimationEffect has some code for animation using gsap and scrolltrigger . Hero section is the section where it need to be trigger , HandleRequest is where every section is called.

This is all the detail i got so far

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';`enter code here`
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger';

export const AnimationEffect = () => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      '.hero-left-wrap',
      {
        autoAlpha: 0,
        x: -30,
      },
      {
        autoAlpha: 1,
        x: 0,
        duration: 0.6,
        delay: 0.5,
        stagger: 0.2,
        ease: 'none',
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: 'section',
          toggleActions: 'play none none none',
        },
      }
    );
    gsap.fromTo(
      '.hero-right-wrap',
      {
        autoAlpha: 0,
        x: 30,
      },
      {
        autoAlpha: 1,
        x: 0,
        duration: 0.6,
        delay: 0.5,
        stagger: 0.2,
        ease: 'none',
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: 'section',
          toggleActions: 'play none none none',
        },
      }
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ScrollTrigger) {
      ScrollTrigger.saveStyles('.hero-left-wrap, .hero-right-wrap');
      ScrollTrigger.refresh();
    }
  }, []);

  return true;
};

export default AnimationEffect;

import cms from '@/cms';
import templates from '@/components/templates';
import Layout from '@/components/layout';
import AnimationEffect from '@/components/gsap';

export default function HandleRequest({ $global, data }) {
    const template = data?.content?.template || '**';
    const Template = templates[template];

    return (
        <Layout $global={$global}>
            <AnimationEffect />
            {!!Template && <Template data={data} />}
            {!Template && <pre>Template not found: {template}</pre>}
        </Layout>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    const response = await cms.handle(ctx, {
        $global: await cms.getGlobalData(),
    });

    if (response?.props?.notFound) {
        ctx.res.statusCode = 404;
    }

    return response;
}

import VideoComp from "@/components/elements/VideoComp";
import Link from "next/link";
import ClutchReview from "../../elements/ClutchReview";

const Hero = ({ data }) => {
  let { title, description, buttons, media_type, video_url, enabledReview , image } =
    data;
  enabledReview = true;

  return (
    <section className="hero-section pt-10 pb-24">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-20">
          <div className="hero-left-wrap">
            <h1 className="font-semibold text-5xl text-secondary leading-[60px]">
              {title}
            </h1>
            <p className="font-medium text-2xl text-dim mt-6 leading-9">
              {description}
            </p>

            {buttons && (
              <div className="mt-12 flex flex-wrap gap-6">
                {buttons.map((butData, id) => (
                  <Link
                    href={butData.button.url}
                    className={
                      butData.type === "primary"
                        ? "primary-btn"
                        : "secondary-btn"
                    }
                    key={id}
                  >
                    {butData.button.title}
                  </Link>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}

            {enabledReview && <ClutchReview />}
          </div>
          <div className="hero-right-wrap relative">
            <VideoComp data={{media_type, video_url,image}} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `useEffect` that runs when which var changed!

The array of it is empty, that means every change makes re-render in all useEffects and it can has no effect on re-rendering the useEffect you want.